# String passed as function parameter is undefined

Tags: javascript, function

When I pass a string to a function as a parameter, it returns `undefined`. Why is that?

```
let a = 'b';

let test = (a) => console.log(a);

test(); // undefined
```

Comment: The `a` from the parameter list shadows the higher scoped `let a = 'b'`. Read how scoping works in JavaScript in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `test();` you aren't putting anything between `(` and `)`, so you aren't passing any parameters.

When you defined `test` (with `(a) =>`) you created a *local* variable `a` that masks the *global* variable with the same name.

To pass `a` you have to actually pass it: `test(a)`.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is that?

Because you don't pass any argument. Try the following:

```
test(a);
```

The following definition:

```
let test = (a) => console.log(a);
```

is like the following:

```
function test(a){
    console.log(a);
}
```

So when you call `test`, without passing any argument the value of `a` would be undefined.