# What is the scope of this global / function variable?

Tags: javascript

In the following code, shouldn't x be considered a global variable?  Thus, when it gets to the console.log line x it should have the value of "World".  However, when I run this code it logs "Hello undefined".  `

```
let x = "World";

function sayHello(x) {
    console.log("Hello ", x);
}

sayHello();
```

But when I change the parameter to y, it then works as I expected, logging "Hello World.

```
let x = "World";

function sayHello(y) {
    console.log("Hello ", x);
}

sayHello();
```

Can someone explain what is going on here?

thanks

Comment: You simply have a global variable that you are attempting to use inside of function scope. Because it's a global variable, it can be accessed from anywhere.

Comment: This question is a million times better than the other one.

Comment: when you call `sayHello()`, you are passing nothing for the argument `x` that it expects in `function sayHello(x)`, so inside of that function, there *is* an `x`, but `x` is undefined.  When you change it to `sayHello(y)`, then there is no `x` local to that function, so it looks at the parent scope, which does have an `x`, so it uses that.

Comment: Nobody should be marking this as duplicate - if you do then you are being incredibly lazy and disingenuous. It is a clear question with a clear problem. The steps taken already have been clearly described.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41526721/5376789) so I don't vote to reopen it.

Comment: @dave: When you say "When you change it to `sayHello(y)`, then there is no `x` local to that function" - - isn't it the case that there _is_ an `x` local to that function, found in the `console.log("Hello", x);` statement? Thanks.

Comment: the `x` in that case is not *local* to that function, it is defined outside of the function (but in a scope that the function has access to).  If there was another `x` defined *inside* of that function, then when you do `console.log(x)`, the `x` would refer to the one inside of the function, not the one outside of it.

Comment: @dave: So does the _parameter_ `x` in the `function sayHello(x)` make `x` local to that function?  That is, does having the `x` in the parameter list essentially the same as defining `x` in the function?  Otherwise, why would having the parameter as `y` produce a different outcome?

Comment: that is correct

Answer (score 1):

The `x` parameter in `sayHello(x)` shadows the global `let x = "World";`. If you pass a value in, `sayHello("Hello")`, you would get an output, `Hello`.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `sayHello(‘Stack Overflow’)`. I’m sure you can guess whet the result will be.

The function is expecting `x` to be the first argument passed to the function. If no argument is passed, the argument `x` is `undefined`.

The technical term for what happened here is *shadowing*. The argument named `x` shadows the variable named `x`, even if no value is passed for the argument.